# C# How can i sum a column of a DataTable after change the Rowfilter?

Tags: c#, datatable, rowfilter, column-sum

I have a `DatagridView`, the users apply filters to it (that are stored in `Datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter`), that means that the number of rows in screen will change, in that case the "TotalCost" variable must change , but it keeps in the same value because i apply "`Compute-(sum)`" and that method is taking all te `Datatable`. Any ida of what could i make to solve this problem? Im workin with 32000+ rows, so i want to evade making a `for loop` if i can.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`CellValidating`** DataGridView event.

***With it you can get the old value and the new value of the cell.***

```
private void myDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
   oldValue = (int)myDataGridView["yourColumn", e.RowIndex].Value;
   //or
   oldValue = (int)myDataGridView[columnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
   //or
   oldValue = (int)myDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
   newValue = (int)e.FormattedValue;

            
   totalCost = totalCost - oldValue;
   totalCost = totalCost + newValue;
}
```

Use the `RowsAdded` event when the user adds a row

```
private void myDataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    newValue =(int)myDataGridView["yourColumn", e.RowIndex].Value;
    totalCost = totalCost + newValue;
}
```

Use the `UserDeletingRow` event when the user deleted a row

```
private void myDataGridView_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    oldValue = (int)myDataGridView["yourColumn", e.Row.Index].Value;
    totalCost = totalCost - oldValue;
}
```

Comment: I think that there are new rows or missing rows, so i don't think that your approach will help. Upvoted anyway since the idea is good and might help someone

Comment: So you have to use 3 events, When changing, When adding a new row and when deleting a row. I responded to all three events.

Comment: ´CellValidating´ doesn't trigger, i think is because i fill the datagrid with a datatable and the user is not able to add or delete rows. Tried the ´RowsAdded´ (not user) event but didn't work properly :(

Comment: You need to manage possible errors, for example not null values to create a clr error. Send me the errors you receive to check